# Custom scrollable view with zooming

Tags: android, android-view, android-scroll

I would like to implement a view that acts as a viewport for a larger content area. The user should be able to scroll horizontally and vertically and zoom by pinching. Think of it as a `MapView`, instead of custom-drawn content instead of a map.

Is there a component that I can use as a base? (Android's `ScrollView` classes won't work, since they only allow scrolling along a single axis).

Comment: You need to start digging the Canvas in java. What type of content you want to show in such component ?

Comment: I will most likely use a `Canvas` to display vector graphics with which the user can interact. The part I'm trying to figure out is the gesture-based scrolling and zooming.

Comment: I can suggest you one opensource library for that. Actually library is to read pdf file. Our concern is pinch zoom-in zoom-out on canvas. That code can help you out. Still need to search a lot in that library.